# Is there a cleaner way to add "else if" to assignment conditional in Awk, etc.?

Tags: scripting, awk, conditional-statements, variable-assignment, compound-assignment

Certain languages like awk script allow for conditional assignments.  For example, say you had a list file in the format:

```
<item name, no spaces> <price as float>
```

e.g.

```
Grape 4.99
JuicyFruitGum 0.45
Candles 5.99
```

And you wanted to tax everything over $1... you could use the awk script:

```
awk '{a=($2>1.00)?$2*1.06:$2; print a}' prices.data
```

...which uses conditional assignment to shorten the syntax.

But say you wanted to also offer $1 off all items over $20 and $2 off items over $40.  Well in a language like c you would typically do something like:

```
if (price > 40.00) {
   price-=2; 
   price *= 1.06; 
}
else if ( price > 20.00 && price <= 40.00 ) {
   price--; 
   price *= 1.06; 
}
else if ( price > 1.00 ) {
   price*=1.06;
}
```

... well I discovered you could kludge awk or other scripting languages into COMPOUND assignment.  e.g.:

```
awk '{a=($2>1.00)?($2>20.00)?($2-1)*1.06:($2>40.00)?($2-2)*1.06:$2*1.06:$2; print a}' prices.data
```

My questions are that 
**a)** is compound assignment (like this) generally universally compatible with scripting languages that support conditional assignment?
**b)** Is there a non-kludge way to do multi-conditional assignment in awk script?

**To clarify:**  I am talking exclusively about the shorthand for assignment (<...>?<...>:<...>;, not traditional conditional assignment, which I already know how to do c-like compound assignment for in Awk script.  As a side note, as to why I might use shorthand, I think the merit is obvious -- that it's short.  But like regexes, you might want to write a good description of what your confusing syntax does for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a)**

Bash, ksh and zsh support compound conditional (ternary) operators (Bash doesn't do floats, though):

```
for i in {3..5}; do for j in {2..6}; do for k in {2..4}; do
    (( a = i > j ? i > k ? j > k ? i * j : i * k : j * k : 0 ))
    echo $a
done; done; done
```

PHP's ternary operator syntax is similar.

Python's is quite different:

```
a = b if c else d if e else f if g else h
```

Bash, et al, and Ruby (which also supports the `?:` form) support this style (showing Bash's version):

```
[[ condition ]] && do_if_true || do_if_false
```

which can be done in a compound form. This can perform actions in addition to assignments.

**b)** no, not without explicit `if`/`else` (or resorting to even more <s>kludginess</s> creativity.

Comment: Wow great answer! You, sir, are truly a scripting expert.  Just the kind of info I was overview for...  Have you ever thought of writing a scripting book? :P

Comment: @Jason: The thought has crossed my mind, but there's no money in books any more.

Comment: A website perhaps then? :P  Seems like theres someway to put that educational talent to good use monetarily.  The frequent (free) help is appreciate though!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, C has the `?` operator too, so you could do the same (fugly) thing with C.

However, you are essentially making write-only code there. If you hadn't told me what that awk statement did, it would be very difficult to figure it out. Why not just go ahead and use `if`?

You'll thank yourself in 6 months when you discover a need to tweak it.

Comment: If you understand the syntax, you could break it out into a series of if statements and it shouldnt be too hard to figure out.  Plus that's what comments in your file of one-liners are for :)  I like it because its SHORT, but I'd prefer a proper compound conditional shortening if there is such a thing...

Answer (score 0):

#### (a) I think so

#### (b) Yes

---

As it happens, your "C" code is almost legal awk. The following slightly tweaked version works just fine as an awk program...

```
/./ {
  price = $1
  if (price > 40.00) {
     price -= 2 
     price *= 1.06 
  } else if ( price > 20.00 && price <= 40.00 ) {
     price-- 
     price *= 1.06 
  } else if ( price > 1.00 ) {
     price *= 1.06
  }
  printf("%6.2f\n", price)
}
```

I took the semicolons out, but nothing bad happens if you leave them in...

Comment: err... I was referring exclusively to the assignment shorthand (<...>)?<...>:<...>  ... I already know how to compound assign using traditional conditionals.  I've added extra clarification to my post just so no one else is confused like you were.

Comment: OK, understood, but you did say "in a language like C", and it was kind of cool that your "C" worked in `awk`.  Obviously, there is a general equivalence in `?:` vs `if-then-else`. Now, the cool frontier is in something like Ruby that lets you say `(x?y:z; whatever; if x ...; and_do_something_else)` and you can put that just anywhere, including arbitrary statements in expressions in ((((())))) ...

Comment: Yea I see where that was a bit confusing... sorry about that.  That sounds like an interesting tool for compound execution in Ruby...